# multer-s3-transform file upload is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, multer-s3

I'm using `multer-s3-transform` to upload file to s3, but before upload I want to resize file, and save in two different size.
Following is my code, no error occur, but file is not uploading.

```
let multer = require("multer-s3-transform");
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const sharp = require('sharp');

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
);

const s3 = new aws.S3();
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    shouldTransform: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
      let originalname = file.originalname;
      file.stream.once('data', async function (firstChunk) {
        let magic = firstChunk.toString('hex', 0, 4);
        let extName = path.extname(originalname).toLowerCase();
        // let filename = req.file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(req.file.originalname);
        if (checkMagicNumbers(magic, extName, req)) {
          console.log("Valid File***************************");
          cb(null, true);
        }
      });
    },
    transforms: [{
      id: 'original',
      key: async function (req, file, cb) {
        let basePath = await getDynamicFilePath(req, false);
        console.log(basePath, "Path ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
        let filePath = basePath;
        let filename;
        if (req.params.container === "resumes") {
          void function (req, file, callback) {
            filename = Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname;
            filePath += "/cropped_" + filename;
          }()
        } else {
          filename = Date.now().toString();
          filePath += "/cropped_" + filename;
        }
        console.log(filePath, "path -------------------");
        cb(null, filePath);
      },
      transform: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, sharp().resize(330, 512))
      }
    }
    {
      id: 'thumbnail',
      key: async function (req, file, cb) {
        let basePath = await getDynamicFilePath(req, false);
        console.log(basePath, "Path ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
        let filePath = basePath;
        let filename;
        if (req.params.container === "resumes") {
          void function (req, file, callback) {
            filename = Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname;
            filePath += "/normal" + filename;
          }()
        } else {
          filename = Date.now().toString();
          filePath += "/normal_" + filename;
        }
        console.log(filePath, "path -------------------");
        cb(null, filename);
      },
      transform: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, sharp().resize(1200, 628));
      }
    }
    ]
  })
}).single("file");
upload(req, res, function (err, filePath) {
  console.log(err, "Error");
  console.log(filePath, "*************");
});
```

Everything is working if I use from `multer-s3`, except image resizing, but with `multer-s3-transform` no error occur, and file is not uploading, and never goes to this lines:

`console.log(err, "Error");
   console.log(filePath, "*************");`

I have found the problem, its in following code block where I want to check file magic number.

```
file.stream.once('data', async function (firstChunk) {
    let magic = firstChunk.toString('hex', 0, 4);
    let extName = path.extname(originalname).toLowerCase();
    // let filename = req.file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(req.file.originalname);
    if (checkMagicNumbers(magic, extName, req)) {
      console.log("Valid File***************************");
      cb(null, true);
    }
  });
```

If I comment this, every thing is working.
It seems when taking magic number of file, file is changed to stream, and upload not work, a way to change stream back to file may work.

Comment: how did you fix it? Please share your answer, I need to do same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me changing to the following worked.

```
let uploadToCloud = (req, res) => {
let bufferUpload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10485760
  }
}).single('file');
bufferUpload(req, res, async function (err) {
  try {
    let buffer = new Buffer(req.file.buffer);
    let magic = buffer.toString('hex', 0, 4);
    let extName = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase();
    let filename;
    if (checkMagicNumbers(magic, extName, req)) {
       // Your codes
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
    res.end();
    return;
  }
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you calculate and check for magic numbers by converting file buffer to hex string instead of converting the file to stream and accessing the same in **data** event handler and then doing the conversion to hex?

```
shouldTransform: function(req, file, cb) {
      const originalname = file.originalname;
      const firstChunk = file.buffer;
      const magic = firstChunk.toString("hex", 0, 4);
      const extName = path.extname(originalname).toLowerCase();
      if (checkMagicNumbers(magic, extName, req)) {
        cb(null, true);
      }
    }
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you are facing any difficulties.

Comment: Thanks, but this line `const firstChunk = file.buffer;` return undefined

Comment: Could you check 2 things for me, see what the value for  `file` is and  try `req.file.buffer` instead of `file.buffer`?

Comment: file is `{ fieldname: 'file',                                                                                                      originalname: 'pexels-photo-1004665.jpeg',                                                                              encoding: '7bit',                                                                                                       mimetype: 'image/jpeg' }` and `req.file.buffer` gives error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined `

Comment: @jones I faced this exact thing. Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: @Sashi Buffer only comes for storage type MemoryStorage